# Copy information from one workbook to another with a specific condition

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I would need a code to allow me to copy paste the information from a workbook called "Target" to another workbook called "Source" based on a specific condition.

This condition is based on the unique Project ID found in the code.

I tried doing some coding but it does not seems to allow me to get the result that I wanted.

The code would only read the first row and copy the information to the other workbook instead of looking through the project ID "10000327" in the "Project ID" column in the Target workbook and copy the information to the Source workbook.

Below is the code that I have tried and gave the result that I mentioned earlier.

Really hope that anyone could help me as I am very new to VBA. Thank you:)

```
Sub AAA()    
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim target As Worksheet
    Dim cellFound As Range



    Set target = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set source = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastrow = source.Range("A" & target.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    lastcol = target.Cells(2, target.Columns.Count).Column

    target.Activate

'For a = 2 To 50
For Each cell In target.Range("A2:A500")
        ' Try to find this value in the source sheet

        Set cellFound = source.Range("A:A").Find(What:="10000327", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then

            cell.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).Copy
            cellFound.Offset(ColumnOffset:=1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

     Else
     Exit Sub


     End If

Next
```

Comment: Is the column called `Project ID` (exactly) and is it in the\ first row of the target worksheet?

Comment: Yes  the column is called Project ID and it is on the first column. The row starts on the 2nd row of the Project ID. @Jeeped

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the hard-coded search term to a var that gets it's pid on successive loops.

```
Sub AAB()
    Dim sWS As Worksheet, tWS As Worksheet
    Dim pidCol As Long, pidRow As Long, pidStr As String, rw as long

    Set tWS = Workbooks("Target.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set sWS = Workbooks("Source.xlsm").Sheets("Sheet2")

    With sWS
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            pidCol = 1
            pidStr = "10000327"  '.Cells(rw, pidCol).Value
            If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Columns(1), pidStr)) Then
                rw = Application.Match(pidStr, .Columns(1), 0)
                With .Cells(rw, 2).Resize(1, .Columns.Count - 1)
                    If CBool(Application.CountIf(tWS.Columns(1), pidStr)) Then
                        pidRow = Application.Match(pidStr, tWS.Columns(1), 0)
                        .Copy Destination:=tWS.Cells(pidRow, 2)
                    End If
                End With
            End If
        End With
    End With

    Set sWS = Nothing
    Set tWS = Nothing
End Sub
```

This loops through all the values in column A (`pidCol = 1`) on the source worksheet and copies the data to the target worksheet if the associated PID is found on the target worksheet.

Comment: Hi, how does the code will look like if it is hard coded? because i would prefer to use a hard code such as setting the project ID in the code so that it would search only the specific project ID that i wanted. @Jeeped

Comment: You would just need to remove the [For Each...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) and hard-code the string you are looking for into the `pidStr` var. The rw it is on can be retrieved with `Application.Match`.

Comment: But there is an error which keep saying type mismatch when i use the codes you gave. @Jeeped

Comment: I did not error control the Application.Match for the source as it should not be asked for if it doesn't exist. I've added that error control now.

Comment: Hi I used the code and it still give type mismatch on the "rw = Application.Match(pidStr, .Columns(1), 0)" line which i don't understand why there is still error. @Jeeped

Comment: You have been using `"10000327"` up to this point but if that iust throwing a mismatch error then those pid numbers must be true numbers not text that look like numbers. Use `CLng(pidStr)` in that match statement.

Comment: Hi, im sorry i dont really understand what you are saying in terms of using the CLng(pidStr) in the match statement. Where exactly it is? @Jeeped

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think what's going on here is that your for loop is running the find command once for each cell, but it runs the same find command, only returning the first match, each time. If you are using the find command, I think you can use a do...while loop more appropriately, then use "findnext." The msdn help gives an example of this which I think is exactly what you want to do:

```
With Worksheets(1).Range("a1:a500") 
Set c = .Find(2, lookin:=xlValues) 
If Not c Is Nothing Then 
    firstAddress = c.Address 
    Do 
        c.Value = 5 
        Set c = .FindNext(c) 
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress 
End If 
End With
```

The other option would be to check if each cell you get to in your for loop matches.

Comment: Hi may i know what does firstAddress and c.Address means? @user2782664